# Access 2010 query for number of working days with holiday table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2010 for some project management tasks on hand. There are tables for projects (tblProjects) and tasks (tblTasks). Apart from Saturdays and Sundays, we have created a holiday table for local public holidays (tblHolidays).

Say I have a task with start date (15-Dec-2014) and end date (30-Dec-2014) Assuming 25 & 26-Dec-2014 are public holidays in tblolidays, is there any way I can calculate the number of working days with reference to tblHolidays WITHOUT using VBA but just access SQL query?

Thanks in advance!
Freddy

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(tblProjects.date) FROM tblHolidays inner join tblProjects ON PK = FK  AND tblHolidays NOT IN tblProjects